# Vuejs 2 not working correctly without 'unsafe-eval' when deployed to Azure Storage

Tags: vuejs2, unsafe-eval

I have an SPA app by Vuejs 2 (using webpack 4.4)

Before I deployed my app to S3 AWS and access through CloudFront.
The CSP I using with S3 AWS does not have 'unsafe-eval' and the site is working normally.

This week I deployed my app to Azure Storage (using the static site feature of storage) but the site is not working (some js function not working as well and there are no error on the console)

If I add 'unsafe-eval' to CSP then it's working.

How can I remove 'unsafe-eval' from CSP but the site is still working with Azure Storage?

I try to build with run-time build. But it's still not work